# Sort all my j.mp links by most clicked

Tags: sorting, url-shortening, bit.ly

Is there any way I can get all of the links associated with my [**j.mp**](https://j.mp) account and arrange them so that the links with the most clicks are at the top?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>**Note:** j.mp is actually bit.ly</sub>

You can use the [Bitly API (link metrics)](https://dev.bitly.com/link_metrics.html) to get the number of clicks for each link.

---

I'm pasting here an [answer from WebMasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/21496/88566) on this topic:
<sub>(I think this question should be migrated)</sub>

> Consider using a URL shortening service such as [bit.ly](http://bit.ly) to [get click data about a list of links](http://dev.bitly.com/link_metrics.html#v3_link_clicks). Here's how it would work:
>
> 1. You'd use bit.ly shortened links for all links in your list.
> 2. When a visitor clicks a bit.ly link, bit.ly increments the click count and stores it on their server.
> 3. When a user visits your page – but before the list is displayed to them – your script would determine how many clicks each link has received using the [/v3/clicks/ method](http://dev.bitly.com/link_metrics.html#v3_link_clicks) from the bit.ly REST API, which returns click data about multiple bit.ly links you supply.
> 4. You would sort this information by the total number of clicks, display the list, and optionally show the number of clicks for each link.
> 5. You may also choose to cache the results of this request in your database and only request new data once an hour/day.